# Find maximum for a timestamp through Spark groupBy dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I would like to find the last record for an ID for a typed DataSet.
I found a solution based on Dataframe : "Find minimum for a timestamp through Spark groupBy dataframe" [Find minimum for a timestamp through Spark groupBy dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427212/find-minimum-for-a-timestamp-through-spark-groupby-dataframe)

But how doing the same with typed dataset ?

Something like :

```
    case class Person(id: Int, name: String, time: Timestamp, kind: String) 

    val ds:DataSet[Person] = Seq(

        (1, "Bob", parseDate("03/08/02 00:00:00"), "P"),
        (1, "Bob", parseDate("04/08/02 00:00:00"), "PI"),
        (1, "Bob", parseDate("03/08/02 12:00:00"), "PE"))
        .toDF("id", "name", "time", "kind").as[Person]

    ds.groupByKey(_.id)
        .agg(max(_.time), _)
    //            .agg(max(struct("time", columnsButTime: _*)) as "all") => Work with Datafrane
    //            .select("all.*")
```

Comment: Can you define what _"the last record"_ is? nit: There's no `DataSet` type.

Comment: This the record with latest time value for one id.
In my exemple, all the record has the same id, so the second one is the latest.

    > (1, "Bob", parseDate("03/08/02 00:00:00"), "P"),
    > (1, "Bob", parseDate("04/08/02 00:00:00"), "PI"),
    > (1, "Bob", parseDate("03/08/02 12:00:00"), "PE"),
    > (2, "Alic", parseDate("03/01/02 12:00:00"), "PE"),
    > (2, "Alice", parseDate("03/01/02 12:05:00"), "PE"),

We expect to have the result :
    > (1, "Bob", parseDate("04/08/02 00:00:00"), "PI"),
    > (2, "Alice", parseDate("03/01/02 12:05:00"), "PE")